# ADAL Library - The client has requested access to a resource which is not listed in the requested permissions in the client's application registration

Tags: ios, swift, adal

I'm trying to use a library to log in to Microsoft's api. My intention is to read and write tasks on my calendar. I am using the following code to access the access code:

```
func get365AcessToken() -> String {
        let clientId = "bb5e40e8-1fcc-XXXXXXXXX"
        let redirectUrl = "XXXXXXXXX-1fcc-47ac-b339-571a52d0f862://auth"

        let authContext = ADAuthenticationContext.init(authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common", error: nil)
        authContext.acquireTokenWithResource("https://graph.windows.net", clientId: clientId, redirectUri: NSURL.init(string: redirectUrl)) { (result) in
            print(result)
            print(result.error.errorDetails)
            print(result.accessToken)
        }
        authContext.parentController = self

        return ""
    }
```

but I reveive this error:

```
2017-05-29 13:05:26.473556 CRM & Sales[1174:988990] ADAL 2.3.0 iOS 10.2 [2017-05-29 16:05:26] ERROR: Error raised: (Domain: "ADOAuthServerErrorDomain" Code: AD_ERROR_SERVER_AUTHORIZATION_CODE ProtocolCode: "access_denied" Details: "AADSTS65005: Invalid resource. The client has requested access to a resource which is not listed in the requested permissions in the client's application registration. Client app ID: bb5e40e8-1fcc-47ac-XXXXXXXXX. Resource value from request: https://graph.windows.net. Resource app ID: 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000. List of valid resources from app registration: 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000.

Trace ID: e2f4f866-1aa1-4fb6-b37e-9ae432174b00

Correlation ID: af10d363-151a-452b-a6d2-a94cd6772ca4

Timestamp: 2017-05-29 16:05:26Z"
```

[this is my settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SUEu.png)

What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you managed to run the sample ios app?https://libraries.io/github/microsoftgraph/ios-swift-connect-rest-sample

Comment: I dont 't try this!

Answer (score 1):

The app has been granted access to the resource with GUID 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000. You are requesting a resource that has GUID 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000.

You should recheck your app permissions.

Comment: Do you know, which permission should be added apart from Windows Azure Active Directory ?

Comment: It is old question, if still anyone facing this issue, just paste the client ID shown in the error message, you will get the API name. For me apart from Windows Azure Active Directory, added Azure Service Management (latest name)